# Make tables with float:left add horizontal scroll bar instead of "stacking" each other on top

Tags: html, css

I have 3 rather wide tables (each take up around 40% of the screen) and I want them to be side by side. The first two are side by side, but the last one gets below the first one.

How do I get a horizontal scroll-bar and allow the "side-by-side"? I have added `float:left` to my `css`

```css
table.info {
    float: left;

}
```

```html
<body>

<table class="info">
    <tr>

        <td>
            <table>
                <h4 align="center">2020</h4>
                <tr>
                    <th style="max-width:100%">Amount</th>
                    <th style="max-width:100%">Notes</th>
                </tr>
                {% for abon in abonnements %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{abon.data|dictionary_items:"2020"|dictionary_items:"amount"|default_if_none:""}}</td>
                    <td>{{abon.data|dictionary_items:"2020"|dictionary_items:"notes"|default_if_none:""}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>


<table class="info">
    <tr>

        <td>
            <table>
                <h4 align="center">2021</h4>
                <tr>
                    <th style="max-width:100%">Amount</th>
                    <th style="max-width:100%">Notes</th>
                </tr>
                {% for abon in abonnements %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{abon.data|dictionary_items:"2021"|dictionary_items:"amount"|default_if_none:""}}</td>
                    <td>{{abon.data|dictionary_items:"2021"|dictionary_items:"notes"|default_if_none:""}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>


<\body>
```

Comment: 3 times 40% is what ...? Exactly, wider than 100% - so of course the browser starts breaking content into the next "line".

Comment: you shout not use `float` for designing purposes. Since 2012 you should sue Flexbox or Grid for aligning Elements next to each other.

Comment: @CBroe that is the point - that is why I want the horizontal scroll bar, such the tables are next to each other and I can scroll through them

Comment: _"that is why I want the horizontal scroll bar"_ - but floating elements doesn't get you one. You would need a container element wide enough for all three table to go next to each other to begin with. And then that overly wide container could cause a scrollbar on its less-wide parent element in turn ... But as @tacoshy said, you should rather not be using float for this to begin with these days.

Comment: Aaah.. okay. That would be an answer, instead of the rather arrogant first  one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Flexbox on the container: `display:flex` to align them next to each other. Then enable scrolling with `overflow-x: scroll`. After that you can prevent the default shrinking to fit behavior by applying `flex-shrink: 0` to the table.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

table {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}


/* for visualization only */
table {
  width: 40%;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table></table>
  <table></table>
  <table></table>
</div>
```